# Datasets for emotion recognition in German dialogues

Tags: data-request, language, germany, audio

I am currently working on the topic of **emotion recognition in German dialogues** (Speech). So far I only managed to find a single dataset related to this topic: [Berlin Database of Emotional Speech](http://emodb.bilderbar.info/docu/).

Is anyone aware of similar **open-sourced** datasets that I can use?

Comment: Is emotional speech different from sentiment?

Comment: Theoretically the concepts are somewhat similar. However, the term sentiment analysis describes the process of classifying the sentiment of the author/speaker as positive, neutral or negative. Whereas emotion recognition/detection describes the process of recognizing certain emotions: happy, calm, surprised, bored, fearful, angry.